# Is working visa rejected a legitimate reason for leaving? Is it good to say so?

Tags: visa, resignation

If you are working overseas, you will require a working visa in that particular country. Suppose your working visa is going to expire, and when the company tries to renew your visa, it is rejected. So you have to apply for a new job at other company. Is it good to state this if it is being asked by your potential employer? I have mixed opinion about this:

- Yes. Because this shows that you have no problem working in your current environment. You don't have difficulty in doing your job, no conflict between you and your colleagues/bosses. So the leaving reason is not caused by you.
- No. Because this might give impression that you are going to lose your job, and your potential employer might use this opportunity to lower your expected salary.

So, should I state this or not?

Comment: There are other things that I can say without lying, such as saying like looking for new challenges and roles, if the position offers me a different role. Usually we would like to make progress in our career, wouldn't we?

Comment: Be aware that there could be reasons for the rejection that would make any new employer unlikely to get the visa and thus may question having a working relationship with you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should say it, because you will in all likelihood at the very least require assistance from them to renew our visa, or you face being deported or worse if you continue to work. In my limited experience this has been pivotal, and yes it has been used against the applicant to reduce their pay.

One main reason for employing people on work visas is that you can usually get the same skills cheaper than it would cost you to hire a local and you have more control over them in various ways. It may seem unfair, but that is what I have seen.

Comment: You should state that you will need visa sponsorship, because that may be a deal breaker. But I would not volunteer that your current visa is expiring, since that's just holding a gun to your own head.